# Считывание в массив int[] чисел до нуля одной строкой через пробел

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Возникла проблема. Для решения одного из заданий, нужно считывать числа в массив int-ов:

> Вводятся числа до тех пор, пока не будет введен 0. Определите, сколько среди них четных.

Если бы вводились числа не в одной строке, то можно было бы через цикл `while`, а как поступать в таком случае, я, к сожалению, не знаю.

Прошу помощи в *реализации*.

Comment: Читаем строку, используя `.Split()` разделяем на массив, проходим по массиву, используем `Int32.TryParse()` для преобразования в `int`, добавляем полученное значение в `int[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).TakeWhile(n => n != 0).Count(n => n % 2 == 0)
```

Разбирайтесь.